# avoid inheriting method in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

The following code snippet

```
class A {
   def foo = "A.foo"
}

trait B {
   def foo = "B.foo"
   def bar = "B.bar"
}

val x = new A with B
```

does not compile because

```
error: overriding method foo in class A of type => java.lang.String;
method foo in trait B of type => java.lang.String needs `override' modifier
```

However, my intention is define x so that:

```
x.foo => "A.foo"
x.bar => "B.par"
```

That is, I only want x to inherit bar from B, but not foo.  Is there a way in scala to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scala> val x = new A with B { override def foo = super[A].foo }
x: A with B = $anon$1@4822f558

scala> x.foo
res0: java.lang.String = A.foo

scala> x.bar
res1: java.lang.String = B.bar
```

It is obviously not something you want to do too often.

Comment: Note also, that while it works fine with defs it gets trickier with vals.

Answer (score 5):

As it doesn't seem like you really want `A with B` to *be* a `B`, but rather to have access to a subset of the behaviour of a `B`, this sounds like a good case for composition over inheritance:

```
class A(val b: B) {
   def foo = "A.foo"
   def bar = b.bar
}

class B {
   def foo = "B.foo"
   def bar = "B.bar"
}

val x = new A(new B)
x.foo => "A.foo"
x.bar => "B.bar"
```

Or, if you need an `A` without a `B` most of the time but sometimes need to be able to call the `bar` method on it, you could do it with an implicit conversion:

```
class A {
  def foo = "A.foo"
}
class B {
  def foo = "B.foo"
  def bar = "B.bar"
}

implicit def a2b(a: A) = new B

val x = new A
x.foo => "A.foo"
x.bar => "B.bar"
```